# How to do Cassandra CQL queries with Astyanax?

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra, cql, astyanax

I'm using Astyanax version 1.56.26 with Cassandra version 1.2.2

Ok, a little situational overview:

1. I have created a very simple column family using cqlsh like so:

   `CREATE TABLE users (
     name text PRIMARY KEY,
     age int,
     weight int
   );`
2. I populated the column family (no empty columns)
3. Querying `users` via cqlsh yields expected results
4. Now I want to programmatically query `users`, so I try something like:

```
ColumnFamily<String, String> users =  
  new ColumnFamily<String, String>("users", StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());
OperationResult<ColumnList<String>> result = ks.prepareQuery(users)
  .getRow("bobbydigital") // valid rowkey
  .execute();
ColumnList<String> columns = result.getResult();
int weight = columns.getColumnByName("weight").getIntegerValue();
```

1. During the assignment of `weight` a NPE is thrown! :(

My understanding is that the `result` should have contained all the columns associated with the row containing `"bobbydigital"` as its row key. I then tried to assign the value in the column named `"weight"` to the integer variable `weight`. I know that the variable `columns` is getting assigned because when I add some debug code right after the assignment, like so:

```
System.out.println("Column names = " + columns.getColumnNames());
```

I get the following output:

`Column names = [, age, weight]`

So why the null pointer? Can someone tell me where I went wrong? Also, why is there blank column name?

UPDATE:
Also if I try querying in a different manner, like so:

```
Column<String> result = ks.prepareQuery(users)
  .getKey("bobbydigital")
  .getColumn("weight")
  .execute().getResult();
int x = result.getIntegerValue();
```

I get the following exception:
`InvalidRequestException(why:Not enough bytes to read value of component 0)`

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing incorrectly. The style of querying I was attempting is not valid with CQL tables. To query CQL tables with Astyanax you need to chain the `.withCQL` method to your `prepareQuery` method; passing a CQL statement as the argument.

Information specific to using CQL with Astyanax can be found [here](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Cql-and-cql3).

Comment: It should be noted that there is currently a bug with Astyanax's CQL handling as noted in the answer to the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579731/cassandra-cql3-support-in-astyanax). For this reason, as that answer suggests, I'm now using the [Java Driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) from Datastax.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by adding setCqlVersion

`this.astyanaxContext = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
                    .forCluster("ClusterName")
                    .forKeyspace(keyspace)
                    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(
                            new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl().setCqlVersion(
                                    "3.0.0").setDiscoveryType(`

And adding `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` while creating the table.